# How can I setup custom hotcorners?

Tags: 14.04, gnome, ubuntu-gnome, gnome-shell-extension

I am currently using **gnome-ubuntu** and I need help in setting up **custom hot corners**.

Let me explain,

When I move my mouse corner to the top left corner, it opens the **Activities** sidebar as any gnome would do. I want to extend it to the other corners as well.

For instance, I want to switch between the workspaces when I point my mouse to the bottom left corner and probably open an Application (say, **Nautilus**) when I point my mouse to the bottom right corner.

My question is, Is there any **package/script/gnome-extension** that can make this possible?

I have tried [**Hot-Corn-Dog**](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/309/hot-corn-dog/) , but it doesn't support **Gnome-Ubuntu 14.04** at the moment.